# Autotask 'auto optimizer stats collection' and scheduler jobs logging

Tags: oracle, statistics

We have a DB hosting Peoplesoft schema, with more than 33.000 tables. Since
december Oracle has left more than 18 thousand of them with no statistics
renewed:

```
SQL> select to_char(last_analyzed,'YYYYMM') ,count(*) from dba_tables where  
   2 owner='SYSADM' group by to_char(last_analyzed,'YYYYMM') order by 1;  

TO_CHA  COUNT(*)  
------ ----------  
202012     18369  
202101        23  
202103        14  
202104       832  
           14490
```

Yet if I check one of them (as an example) within these 18369 tables, I find
it has been modified way above the 10% default threshold for stats
recomputation; select from dba_tab_modifications shows:

```
TABLE_NAME             INSERTS   UPDATES   DELETES TIMESTAMP  
-------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------  
PS_JOB                    8063    181375       395 12-APR-21  
  
SQL> select t.table_name,ts.stale_stats,  
   2 t.monitoring,t.last_analyzed,t.num_rows from dba_tables t,dba_tab_statistics  
   3 ts where t.owner=ts.owner and t.table_name='PS_JOB' and  
   4 ts.table_name='PS_JOB';  

TABLE_NAME          STALE_S MON LAST_ANAL  NUM_ROWS  
-------------------- ------- --- --------- ----------  
PS_JOB              YES    YES 08-DEC-20    162039  

SQL> select count(*) from sysadm.ps_job;  

 COUNT(*)  
----------  
   180794
```

In DBA_AUTOTASK_JOB_HISTORY or DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS views the
analyze-table jobs "ORA$AT_OS_OPT_SY_nnnnn" never take more than 35 to 40
minutes.

Yet this table is skipped from all stats recomputations that occur every day...

I have 2 questions:

- Someone knows if internal process doing stats recomputing job (i.e.
  procedure DBMS_STATS.GATHER_DATABASE_STATS_JOB_PROC, which is not documented)
  is logged somewhere with relevant details ?? (I'm very surprised that, given
  the amount of tables this schema contains, it only takes a little more than
  half an hour to complete...)
- What are conditions, or tests performed by DBMS_STATS in the background to
  yield list of tables of which statistics should be recalculated ?? (why this
  PS_JOB table hasn't been recomputed yet since Dec, 8th ??, in spite of its
  growth)

In advance - thanks a lot.

Regards,
Sebino

Comment: What is your Oracle version?
Are there any errors in the alert log about stats gathering?

Comment: Version is 18c.

Comment: Simplest explanation: statistics are locked on those tables. Check `STATTYPE_LOCKED` column in `DBA_TAB_STATISTICS`.

Comment: No they're not. I checked that of course before posting here.

Comment: The built in stats job writes a trace file but I do not believe that it shows why it makes the choices it does. You could disable the built in job and write your own stats gathering job and then you would have full control over the logic that it uses. A lot of the PeopleSoft tables are empty and unused unless you are using every feature but PS_JOB is not one of those obviously. Do you have evidence that the older statistics are causing a performance problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select sample_size from dba_tables where table_name='PS_JOB';
```

What does that return?

If that number is not as expected, is it possible another DBA used something like `DBMS_STATS.SET_GLOBAL_PREFS`
in this way for example:

```
EXEC DBMS_STATS.set_global_prefs('estimate_percent', '20');
```

instead of using the default of `DBMS_STATS.AUTO_SAMPLE_SIZE`? (which may be more than 10 itself)

That figure of 20 would change it from the traditional default of 10.  However AUTO_SAMPLE_SIZE will have Oracle determine the value and that may have been set, and Oracle chose a value larger than 10.

I am also in the dark about 'auto optimizer stats collection' and exactly how it has been working internally since 11g.  We have some windows though (8 total) that run for longer than 3 hours of stats gathering on our production databases.